# svn: how to set the executable bit on a file?

Tags: svn, executable, chmod

How do I set the executable bit on a file in an svn repository?

I've tried:

```sh
chmod +x sync.py
svn commit sync.py -m "Make sync.py executable"
```

But the change was not propagated.

How do I set the executable bit in the svn repository?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

svn uses `propset` to change file attributes:

```
svn propset svn:executable ON sync.py
```

Comment: Is there a 'writable' flag as well?